Odoo 17 on macOS: ImportError for psycopg2 with Python 3.12
I’m encountering an issue while trying to run Odoo 17 with Python 3.12. The error occurs when executing the odoo-bin command with the configuration file odoo.conf. The traceback indicates a problem with loading a shared library required by psycopg2.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdulrhman/PycharmProjects/odoo17/pythonProject/odoo17/odoo-bin", line 5, in 
    import odoo
  File "/Users/abdulrhman/PycharmProjects/odoo17/pythonProject/odoo17/odoo/_psycopg.cpython-312-darwin.so
  Reason: no LC_RPATH's found

Process finished with exit code 1

Context:
Python Version: 3.12
Odoo Version: 17
Operating System: macOS
Environment: Virtual environment created with Python 3.12
Python Version:
I initially attempted to run Odoo 17 using Python 3.12, as I had it installed on my system. I created a virtual environment with Python 3.12 and installed the required dependencies using pip install -r requirements.txt.
Installing Dependencies:
After setting up the environment, I ran into the ImportError related to psycopg2 and the missing libpq.5.dylib. I tried reinstalling psycopg2 and checking for any missing dependencies or library paths, but the issue persisted.
Alternative Approaches: Attempted to install Python 3.10 or 3.11 using Homebrew, but Python 3.12 was already installed.

i would suggest you to use pyenv to manage your python env so you dont break your local python. please try installing python 3.10 or 3.11 with it and try. I think that will resolve your issue https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv if not let me know

I have faced the same problem for my config
Python Version: 3.12
Odoo Version: 17
Operating System: macOS
Solution:
Try to Install the requirement 'psycopg2-binary ' instead of psycopg2
pip3 install psycopg2-binary

Hope it will helps you.

Are you using MacOS or running an instance in Multipass?
Either way:

Create a virtual environment with Python 3.10

Install the requirements in the virtual environment.


Afterwards you'll always need to have the virtual environment active in order to run Odoo.
Check my post: https://www.erpgap.com/blog/odoogap-blog-1/setup-odoo-macos-multipass/
Let me know if helped.

Post link just leads to the homepage and you do not explain why doing this in Python 3.10 will fix anything
